# The background color changes after the for loop exits. Can anyone explain?

Tags: java

CellPane is a JPanel. In constructor i have added a mouse listener.When clicked the background should change to blue and then print on console the values. But the problem is first the values are printed and then the background changes. Why?

```
public CellPane() {
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    defaultBackground = getBackground();
                    setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                    for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++)
                    {
                        System.out.println(i);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    setBackground(defaultBackground);
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the color only changes when the component gets repainted. And the repaint happens on the swing thread (there is only one thread) which is the same thread that your event handler runs on. So by holding on to the thread and not returning immediately, you are delaying the repaint. And your print happens before the repaint as well.